# Android Studio 2021.3.1 preview issues with Dji Widgets

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, dji-sdk

A couple of months ago with Android Studio update the preview stops rendering of xml code if there is any dji widget inside.

```
<dji.ux.beta.core.panel.topbar.TopBarPanelWidget
<dji.ux.panel.CameraSettingAdvancedPanel
...
```

> Android Failed to instantiate one or more classes.
> The following classes could not be instantiated:
> - dji.ux.beta.core.panel.topbar.TopBarPanelWidget (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

I tried to add "Base." before Theme, but it looks like something is wrong with the dji sdk.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest update of Android Studio i.e. Dolphin | 2021.3.1, there are many unresolved bugs so don't worry.

> Try Invalidate and Restart option
> After restarting if it still shows the some error, check whether you have
> used any third party library's tag into that xml file.

Because I also faced the same issue and later on found out that it was occurring due to that third party lib's tag. If present, try to comment that particular code and check whether the preview appears or not.

You can try to install previous version of Android Studio and try again, but I think that it doesn't work with dji-sdk.